# Экспорт таблицы из Excel в Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, excel

Есть файл .xls
В нём 5 листов с таблицами.

Код парсирует только 1 лист, и не даёт возможности между ними переключиться, а также нет возможности редактировать таблицы внутри Swing-а и сохранять их в тот же excel-файл, что сильно необходимо.

Также съезжает почему-то шапка заголовков столбцов,когда делаешь прокрутку в сторону и не видно следующих. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код :

```
package kursach;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

    public class excelTojTable extends JFrame {

    static JTable table;
    static JScrollPane scroll;
    // header is Vector contains table Column 
    static Vector headers = new Vector();
    // Model is used to construct JTable
    static DefaultTableModel model = null;
    // data is Vector contains Data from Excel File 
    static Vector data = new Vector();
    static JButton jbClick;
    static JFileChooser jChooser;
    static int tableWidth = 0;
    // set the tableWidth
    static int tableHeight = 0;
    // set the tableHeight

        public excelTojTable() {
        super("Import Excel To JTable");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        jChooser = new JFileChooser();
        jbClick = new JButton("Select Excel File");
        buttonPanel.add(jbClick, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Show Button Click Event 
        jbClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                jChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                File file = jChooser.getSelectedFile();
                if (!file.getName().endsWith("xls")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select only Excel file.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    try {
                        fillData(file);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(excelTojTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
                tableWidth = model.getColumnCount() * 150;
                tableHeight = model.getRowCount() * 25;
                table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(tableWidth, tableHeight));
                table.setModel(model);
            }
        }
    });
    table = new JTable();
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setBackground(Color.pink);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setEnabled(false);
    table.setRowHeight(25);
    table.setRowMargin(4);
    tableWidth = model.getColumnCount() * 150;
    tableHeight = model.getRowCount() * 25;
    table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(tableWidth, tableHeight));
    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setBackground(Color.pink);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(600, 600);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * * Fill JTable with Excel file data. * * @param file * file :contains xls
 * file to display in jTable
 */
void fillData(File file) throws IOException {
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        headers.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
            Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(i, 0);
            headers.add(cell1.getContents());
        }
        data.clear();
        for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows(); j++) {
            Vector d = new Vector();
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i, j);
                d.add(cell.getContents());
            }
            d.add("\n");
            data.add(d);
        }
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new excelTojTable();
}
}
```

среди подключенных библиотек внутри проекта,есть jxl.jar и poi apache.

Comment: среди подключенных библиотек внутри проекта,есть jxl.jar и poi apache.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman дополнил

Comment: класс `BasicTableHeaderUI`, отвечающий за рисование заголовка, при определении размера суммирует предпочтительные размеры всех колонок, а поскольку они нигде не задаются и по умолчанию равны 75, то ширина заголовка выходит в 2 раза меньше, и он съезжает. Вместо `table.setPreferredSize` вызывайте что-то вроде `Collections.list( table.getColumnModel().getColumns() ).forEach( c -> c.setPreferredWidth( 150 ) );`

Comment: @zRrr попробую. Но вот,что делать с листами и возможностью редактирования?